# How to get parent of the class?

Tags: python-3.x, class, object

Here is my code:

```py
class MyObject:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    @property
    def parent(self) -> Test:
        return  # Return Test instance


class Test:
    def __init__(self, first: MyObject, second: MyObject):
        self.first = first
        self.second = second


Test(
    first=MyObject(),
    second=MyObject()
)
```

I have a `Test` class that takes two arguments into which objects of another class should be passed. How can I get the parent instance of the `Test` object from the `MyObject` class without passing `self`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Test` is not the parent of the `MyObject`. `Test` contains `MyObject`.

`Myobject` can not know `Test` unless you pass it